# Trouble using plugin with Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, plugins, npm, ionic3

https://github.com/blinkmobile/cordova-plugin-sketch

i found this Little plugin and want to use it in my Ionic 3 app.
Sadly i have Trouble using it, because after succesfully installing it with

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/blinkmobile/cordova-plugin-sketch.git
```

VSCode says all the time: "Property 'sketch' does not exist on type 'Navigator'."

Is this maybe not compatible with Ionic or am I hopefully just missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window.navigator, should declare `window` first.

Try with:

```
declare const window: any;

...

window.navigator.sketch
```

Comment: Do you have ecperience with the mentioned plugin?

Comment: @felix9607 no, first time I see this plugin :D